# Choosing files look different on Mac OS when using FileDialog and JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Currently my app is written using JFileChooser but I prefer the FileDialog look and feel when selecting files. Is there anyway to change the look and feel of JFileChooser for Mac OS X to make it look like the FileDialog?

Answer (score -1):

You can change the look and feel of certain objects with UIManager and Swing Utilities  and even revert back to the original look and feel.

```
import javax.swing.plaf. *;    
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
JFileChooser file = new JFileChooser();
LookAndFeel Revert = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
LookAndFeel LF = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName(); // Mac OS
try{
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(LF);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(file); // Changes file to current look and feel
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(Revert); // Remove this is you don't want to revert.
}
catch (Exception Fail) {
System.out.println(Fail);
}

}
}
```